# vue 2 - button @click not working when input has :focus with height change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've got simple form with one textarea and button. I'm using vue and axios to send textarea data after button click.

Everything worked ok, I can use :focus to e.g. change input border but stopped working when I've used :focus to change height of the textarea.

When I'm clicking button textarea is loosing focus properly, height is changing to default but event on button isn't fired. When I click button again (when textarea isn't on focus) that button works ok and triggers @click event.

html:

```
<form>
<textarea v-model="msg2" @keyup.enter="clickADD" id="wallpost" ></textarea>
<button type="button" @click="clickADD">ADD</button>
</form>
```

css:

```
#wallpost {
    height: 2em;
} 

#wallpost:focus
 {
    height: 5em;
}
```

vue js:

```
methods: {
    clickADD: function (e) {
            console.log('clickADD');
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xan1222o/

I've tried also add .focus class but also without result:

html:

```
<form>
<textarea v-model="msg2" :class="{focus : postFocus}" @focus="postFocus = true" @blur="postFocus = false"  @keyup.enter="clickADD" id="wallpost" ></textarea>
<button type="button" @click="clickADD">ADD</button>
</form>
```

css:

```
#wallpost.focus {
    height: 5em;
}
```

What is the best way to handle css :focus on input and trigger @click on button?

Answer (score 4):

It is because click event hasn't be finished since height changed when the button released.
How about try to replace click with mousedown? It's not a radical solution but works in your case.
[Code Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/ocau3gwc/)

```
<button type="button" @mousedown="clickADD">ADD</button>
```

Comment: thanks @choasia - you solution works, but I'm not sure how safe and universal is to use mousedown instead of (at)click for handling that event.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what do you mean by "safe", it just triggers native mousedown event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

Comment: I mean something that can be full replacement for click (at least in that situation). Will be triggered always when required and not make conflict with other events (triggering in different order or blocking something). But I'll test that because it looks like simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Sure. Don't be hesitate to show me your result if you found any side effect.

Answer (score 1):

**What's happening**: on mousedown outside the textarea, it loses focus, causing the redraw to move the button before the mouseup completes the click. If you hold the mouse down instead of releasing, then move the mouse over the button, then release, you complete the click in the button and the click trigger fires. Unfortunately, that's not a reasonable expectation of user behavior.

**What you can do**: control the appearance with a class, which you set on focus, and on blur, you wait until the mouse has left the Add button to remove:

```
<textarea v-model="msg2" id="wallpost" ref="ta" @focus="setActive" @blur="clearActive"></textarea>
<button type="button" @click="clickADD" @mouseenter="allowBlur(false)" @mouseleave="allowBlur(true)">ADD</button>
```

...

```
setActive(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('active');
},
clearActive() {
  if (this.blurAllowed) {
    this.$refs.ta.classList.remove('active');
  }
},
allowBlur(whether) {
  this.blurAllowed = whether;
  this.clearActive();
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xan1222o/3/)

Comment: It looks like @blur is not working for me. .active class isn't removed on losing focus. I checked in opera and chrome.

Comment: change the `this.nextTick(()` to `this.$nextTick(()`. It will work fine.

Comment: yep, it's handling @blur properly now, but clickADD stopped working (when textarea is focused) - so I'm in the starting point. (at)blur is working, (at)click is working, but they are not working together. My goal is to shrink textarea on blur and submit data through clickADD when I click the button. But textarea should be also shrank always when losing focus.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @Pradeepb.

Comment: @RoyJ I'm not basing on :focus, I'm trying to use your solution https://jsfiddle.net/xan1222o/2/ - class .active is added and removed by focus and blur but as I described above clickADD is not fired when textarea is on focus. Is it working for you? I can use choasia's solution but I prefer use (at)click when I'm handling button click.

Comment: @t.gorski See if the updated solution works for you.

Comment: @RoyJ it's working now, thank you. But it's looks like that solution and generally the way how vue (oj JS) is handling that is slightly overcomplicated regarding to something as simple as blur. I'll give a try your and choasia's solution. I prefer simpler version but I have to research more about differences between click and mousedown.

Comment: This is not particular to Vue, it is just the order of events. The click is not complete until mouseup, but the blur happens after mousedown.